# How to Get Sides of Floating Div Flush with Page?

Tags: html, css, floating, divider

So I have a div that I need flush with the left and right edges of the page. It also must be responsive to the proceeding layout (so the page can re-size). As far as I know, the most efficient way to do this is with a floating layout. How do I get the edges of the div flush with the edges of the screen? Here's my current CSS:

```
#work {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

I tried left: 0px and right: 0px, which obviously didn't work (probably because it's floating...)

In the case that there's no way to do this, how would I make it flush while still responsive to the rest of the page? I get the feeling that this is one of those age-old questions of new web developers...

Comment: can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your `html` and any other `css` please

Comment: Yep. This is the basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/x6duerbd/

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using floats for this kind of basic layout.

Make sure you are reseting the default browser added margin and padding then you can just use `display: inline-block` to do what you want.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That worked, but it reset the padding and margins of every other element on the page to 0. Keep in mind I have content above this. Everything scrunched up at the top (as expected). Is there another way?

Comment: The browser margins and paddings are different for every browser. Have you checked your site on Firefox yet? What about IE. You will probably notice some differences you don't want created by their different margin/padding defaults. Using the asterisk is a super super general rule ensures you always start with the margin/padding you expect. My advice to you is to re-add those margins/paddings on the elements you want and go forward from there. Though you can selectively reset the margin and paddings for just this one area instead I would not advise that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider your responsive framework and you will be able to do this with literally one line of code. All responsive frameworks (Bootstrap, Foundation, skeleton, etc) have a full width class.

Since I use Bootstrap 99.99% of the time, and I suggest you do as well, I will show you that one.

```
<div class="container-fluid thisContainer">

</div>

.thisContainer{
    background:#ccc;
    height:200px;
 }
```

And that is it! That easy! Here's a demo if you wanna play around with it

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwzada)

Comment: You're suggesting that you should almost always use bootstrap on any project? Is this really good advice? Not being sarcastic, I would really like to know, to you, what makes it necessary to use a css framework all the time?

Comment: Yes, I could use Bootstrap, but being a new coder I'm trying to learn everything I can about the way CSS works, and thus want to know how to do it myself. I don't want to be reliant on anything else. Is that literally the ONLY way to do it? I mean this can't be an uncommon problem...

Comment: Bootstrap is the most commercially used front end framework. It's very robust, reliable, and it's javascript is like no other. Not to mention they make hundreds of Bootstrap-friendly aditional jqueries you can add for more functionalities. I work with very large projects and professional environments (i.e. the State of Pennsylvania welfare, The department of Veteran Affairs, and Pennsylvania CareerLink) In over 10 years of experience, I have dealt with many front end frameworks and Bootstrap is by far the best way to go. In my opinion. I'm sure many developers here will agree

Comment: Yeah, Bootstrap is fine, but I want to be able to do it by hand to widen my understanding of the language. Is it really that complex?

Comment: If you want to build a responsive system from scratch go ahead. I commend you for it. But I think you'll learn more from using one that is built. That way you know what it's supposed to look like. You will still have to modify the responsive classes accordingly anyway to make it fit your site. But, sure go ahead! Get to it. You will definitely be around here a lot but you will learn